# An unhandled exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll

Tags: c#, json

I get a error with Newtonjson when parsing my data from Facebook ajax.

> An unhandled exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll
>
> Additional information: Unterminated string. Expected delimiter: ". Path 'payload.entries[364].text', line 1, position 277614.
> Please send me a solution to solve that error .

Comment: Can you post the data you are trying to parse... This isn't really enough information to tell you what's wrong aside  from the obvious.

You have an unterminated string in your json meaning a string somewhere is missing a ' or " or there is an extra ' that wasn't escaped.

Comment: Thanks for replying me. This is my data http://notepad.cc/kikratre42.

Comment: The json you posted parses fine for me....  I suspect your are doing something with the json somewhere that is making it invalid.

Comment: @ryios : Could you give me your code?

Comment: It's below in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put your json in a console application to see if it loads.

I was able to parse it fine using this code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Assembly asm = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Program));
        using (var stream = asm.GetManifestResourceStream("ConsoleApplication1.json.json"))
        {
            TextReader tr = new StreamReader(stream);
            var json = tr.ReadToEnd();
            var thing = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
        }
    }
```

Note: ConsoleApplication1.json.json above is an embeded resource called "json.json" in which I put the json you linked in.

I suspect you are doing something in your code somewhere with the json that is making it invalid.

Comment: thanks for your help. I have been successfully fixed it. :)